# Raise exception as e in if statement

Tags: python, exception, logging, smtp

I have come up with some code to send a file's exceptions as an email, and update a .txt log file. This method works for the following example:

```
from send_mail import send_error_email
from datetime import datetime
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='log.txt', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s')
logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)

now = datetime.now()
date = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

try:
    a = 2 + 'seven'
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    send_error_email(exception=e, message="Can't add string and int")
    logging.exception('Oh no! Error on {} at {} Here is the traceback info:'.format(date, time))
```

However, the functions I want to apply it to have a lot of `if/else` syntax where exceptions are raised in the `if` or `else` block. Here are two examples:

```
def is_empty(test_df):
    if(test_df.empty):
        raise Exception("The sheet: {} is empty".format(sheet_name))
    else:
        pass
    for col in test_df.columns:
        miss = test_df[col].isnull().sum()
        if miss>0:
            raise Exception("{} has {} missing value(s)".format(col,miss))
    return None
```

or

```
def column_validation(sheet_name, input_file, expected_columns, input_columns, months):
    if len(expected_columns) == len(input_columns):
        for i in range(len(input_columns)):
            if input_columns[i] != expected_columns[i]:
                if sheet_name == "G2 30yr":
                    if input_columns[i][:3] in months:
                        continue
                elif sheet_name != "G2 30yr":
                    if input_columns[i] in months:
                        continue
                else:
                    raise Exception("The {} sheet of file: {}'s columns are not in expected format.".format(sheet_name, input_file))
    else:
        raise Exception("Number of columns in file: {}, {} sheet are not as expected".format(input_file, sheet_name))
    return None
```

I'm not sure how to employ the emailing and log function with exceptions that are raised outside of `try/except` blocks where I can access the Exception attributes using `except Exception as e:`. The below `else` will send the email notification but will not correctly update the log file.

```
else:
    send_error_email(exception=e, message="Can't add string and int")
    logging.error('Oh no! Error on {} at {} Here is the traceback info:'.format(date, time), stack_info = True)
```

Comment: Please, post [mre]. You talk of functions but there are none in your code. I guess you actually want catch the exception from function WHEN you call it and then log/send email with the error information

Comment: Sorry, will post an example function. Added two examples.

Comment: Still hard to tell how your code is structured, but you might benefit from a decorator.

Comment: You need to put the `try/except` around the code that calls the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def catch_exception_and_send_email(func):
    def exception_catcher(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception e:
            print(e)
            now = datetime.now()
            date = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
            time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            send_error_email(exception=e, message="Can't add string and int")
            logging.exception('Oh no! Error on {} at {} Here is the traceback info:'.format(date, time))
    return exception_catcher
```

Now, use this to decorate the functions you anticipate possibly raising exceptions:

```py
@catch_exception_and_send_email
def is_empty(test_df):
    # function body


@catch_exception_and_send_email
def column_validation(sheet_name, input_file, expected_columns, input_columns, months):
    # function body
```

Now, whenever any of your decorated functions are called, the decorator's code will run, first `try`ing your function's code, and if your function `raise`s an exception, the decorator catches it, logs it, and sends the email.

I'd also suggest implementing custom exceptions, but that's beside the point here.

Comment: Oh, very neat. I will give that a shot. I do have some custom exceptions (I think) in my functions. How could I apply those to the decorator?

Comment: @Julien check out [Real Python's article](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/), it's a good starting point.

Comment: If I added `send_error_email(exception=e, message="An exception occurred in {}".format(func))` to the `message` variable in the `exception_catcher` function, would it return the name of the function where the exception occurred if one is raised? Additionally, instead of `return None` for those function, could I just put `pass`?

Comment: You can access the name of the function as `func.__name__` -- as for your second question I'm not sure I follow. You should not generally use `pass` in place of `return None`, however.

Comment: Okay sounds good. Thank you! And sorry, I was asking about `pass` since you had that in your code example.

Comment: I included those because I made no changes to your code and including them would've cluttered the answer with irrelevant information, that's all. Don't forget to accept my answer if you find it sufficient.

Comment: Okay, sounds good. Thank you. I will go ahead and accept it. One last question I had is that you mentioned custom exceptions. I do have those in my if and else statements, so I was wondering how I could access those using the decorator if those exceptions are the reason a code piece fails. For example, there are different reasons/levels at which an exception could be thrown in either of those example functions. Or perhaps that is in-built to the decorator functionality?

Comment: To get info on the exception being handled, look into [`sys.exc_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info)

Comment: When I add `@exception_catcher` before a function, it throws an error that says `NameError: name 'exception_catcher' is not defined`. Should I do `@catch_exception_and_send_email` instead?

Comment: Yes, the name of the decorator is `catch_exception_and_send_email`, the `exception_catcher` is only defined inside and is not available in the global scope.

Comment: Got it. Do you want to update that in your answer?

Comment: Ahh, my apologies.